# For loop and map diff

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, es6-promise

I got two cases which I tried to understand what is happen but it still not clear enough form me ,so I read that if I want to run async call in for loop or map I need to use Promise.all
but let me share what happen with me

First I used map to update many records in my database ,It updated some and not all the data

```
AllAuthToken.map(async singleToken =>{
          let deviceIds = uuidv4();
        let newDeviceArray = {
          [deviceIds]: singleToken.deviceToken,
        };
        await AuthToken.updateOne(
          { _id: singleToken._id },
          {
            $set: {
              tokensDeviceArray: [newDeviceArray],
              deviceId: [deviceIds],
            },
          },
          { $new: true }
        );
}
```

Then after this happened I used for loop and it updated all the data

```
  for (let i = 0; i < AllAuthToken.length; i++) {
    let deviceIds = uuidv4();
    let newDeviceArray = {
      [deviceIds]: AllAuthToken[i].deviceToken,
    };
    await AuthToken.updateOne(
      { _id: AllAuthToken[i]._id },
      {
        $set: {
          tokensDeviceArray: [newDeviceArray],
          deviceId: [deviceIds],
        },
      },
      { $new: true }
    );
  }
```

So what happen so that the first case failed and the second passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `.map` executes its callback one after the other without waiting. The `await` does its thing, but that only delays the code that follows after that `await`. But it does not prevent the `.map` iteration to continue with the next call of the callback, as it is not part of the `async` function in which the `await` occurs.

The `for` loop on the other hand, is part of the *same* `async` function as where the `await` occurs, and so the iteration only continues when the awaited promise resolves.

If you prefer to have the database requests executed in "parallel", i.e. where you launch the next request without waiting for the previous one to resolve, then use `Promise.all`, like this:

```
let promises = AllAuthToken.map(singleToken => {
    let deviceIds = uuidv4();
    let newDeviceArray = {
        [deviceIds]: singleToken.deviceToken,
    };
    return AuthToken.updateOne(
        { _id: singleToken._id },
        {
            $set: {
                tokensDeviceArray: [newDeviceArray],
                deviceId: [deviceIds],
            },
        },
        { $new: true }
    );
};

await Promise.all(promises);
/* ... now all is done ... */
```